# Prototypal Inheritance: where to find the message property of Error instance?

Tags: javascript

```
let x=new Error();
x.message="Hello";
Object.keys(x) //["message"]
```

The above makes absolute sense; `message` is a property of `x` instance of `Error`

```
let y=new Error("Morning");
y.message;   //"Morning"
Object.keys(y) // []
Object.getPrototypeOf(y);  // {name: "Error", message: "", constructor: ƒ, toString: ƒ}
```

The question is: ***Where does message exist if neither in the y instance itself nor in the prototype chain?***

Comment: `console.dir(y)` shows you `message` being an own property of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will only include *own* and *enumerable* properties. Now it happens that an `Error` object *inherits* a ***non***-enumerable property `message`, so you don't see it with `Object.keys`, but it certainly is there.

You can list also ***non***-enumerable properties with [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames):

```js
let y=new Error("Morning");
console.log(y.message);   //"Morning"
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(y)); 
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(y));
```

Comment: You mean inside the instance? How can I see that?